# I want to know the length of 'array' using 'while loop' but the code shows error

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var length = 0 while (true) { if (arr.charAt(length) == '') { break } else { length++ } } console.log(length)
```

Comment: `arr.length` will return the length of the array

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: Also, `charAt` is a string method. You're using it on an array.

Answer (score 1):

`arr.length` is the suggested method to find the length of an array.

If you still want to use `while` loop to find the length. Use below code

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let i = 0;
while (arr[i]) {
  i++;
}
console.log(i);
```